I am getting if 'data' in data and 'jobs' in data['data']: TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable this error
In this project we want to fetch metadata of UID and all the metadata has to convert into csv file so I want to add timebound to json query which has to fetch data within 24 hours but I encountered this error from below code:
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, timezone
end_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
start_time = end_time - timedelta(days=1)
end_time_str = end_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
start_time_str = start_time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3] + 'Z'
 

url = 'https://api.skedulo.com/graphql/graphql'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': 'your access token'}
query_1 = {
    "query": f"""
        query {{
            jobs(
                after: null,
                orderBy: "UID",
                filter: "JobStatus == 'Complete' AND ActualEnd >= '{start_time_str}' AND ActualEnd <= '{end_time_str}'"
            ) {{
                edges {{
                    cursor
                    node {{
                        UID
                        Name
                    }}
                }}
                pageInfo {{
                    hasNextPage
                }}
            }}
        }}
    """
}
response = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(query_1), headers=headers, verify=True)
data = response.json()
print(response.content)
uids = []
if 'data' in data and 'jobs' in data['data']:
    for job in data['data']['jobs']['edges']:
        uids.append(job['node']['UID'])
else:
    print("No valid data found in the response.")
 
print(uids)

I am getting this error from above code:
b'{"data":null,"errors":[{"message":"Expected type \'EQLQueryFilterJobs\', found \'\\"JobStatus == \\\\\\"Complete\\\\\\" AND ActualEnd >= \'2024-06-20T08:46:10.143Z\' AND ActualEnd <= \'2024-06-21T08:46:10.143Z\'\\"\'. Expected: InstantTag got StringTag (line 6, column 25):\\n                filter: \\"JobStatus == \\\\\\"Complete\\\\\\" AND ActualEnd >= \'2024-06-20T08:46:10.143Z\' AND ActualEnd <= \'2024-06-21T08:46:10.143Z\'\\"\\n                        ^","locations":[{"line":6,"column":25}]}]}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mendrev\Downloads\GOLD BUG POC\sampleuid.py", line 38, in <module>
    if 'data' in data and 'jobs' in data['data']:
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable
has context menu


Well, data['data'] is null/None, thus in data['data'] raises this error. You might also want to check that data['data'] is a dict, or at least not falsey. E.g.: if data.get('data') and 'jobs' in data['data']:…

The real problem you'll probably want to solve though is Expected type 'EQLQueryFilterJobs', found '\"JobStatus…. If you solved that, you'd probably also get a valid data value back.

What is the object requests ? I pasted your code and found no definition for it.
The error you got seems to indicate that data object is None. NoneType is not iterable (as indicated in the error message), which means you cannot check its 'elements' to see if one of them is called 'data'.
I suggest:
if data:
    if 'data' in data and 'jobs' in data['data']:
        for job in data['data']['jobs']['edges']:
            uids.append(job['node']['UID'])
    else:
        print("No valid data found in the response.")

This way the code will just skip if the retrieved data is None. You may also add an else to the if I added with another print message.
But I guess this is not the core of your problem. If the data being returned is none, the problem may lie in your query, which goes outside my domain.
